# Can you set an Interval on button clicks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

```
$('.button').click();
```

The above code works great to click all buttons on the page at once, but I am trying to fire off clicks every half or second or so until the jQuery Object has looped i.e.

```
$(function(){

   $('.button').each(function(){

          setInterval('$(this).click()', 500);

    });
});
```

Can some one tell me how I can do this? the above code obviously does not work. Am I missing something?

Comment: What do you mean by "until the jQuery Object has looped," what "jQuery object"?

Comment: I am probably referring too it the wrong way. Is the $('.button') a jQuery object that is getting looped through with the each method? Please excuse my noobness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use strings in `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()`. Always pass function objects:

```
$(function() {
    $('.button').each(function(){
        var button = $(this);
        setInterval(function() {button.click();}, 500);
    });
});
```

**EDIT:** If all you want is to trigger a click, this can also be expressed more simply as (thanks icambron):

```
$(function() {
    $('.button').each(function(){
        setInterval($(this).click, 500);
    });
});
```

Comment: `setInterval(button.click)` works on its own, right? No reason to wrap in an extra function

Comment: There are, many reasons you may want to wrap it in a function, one of which would be to define the scope in which it would function

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
   var buttons = $('.button');
   var len = buttons.length;
   var intr = new Array();
   buttons.each(function(i){
          var $this = $(this);
          var timeClick = function(){
             if(i < len ){
                $this.click();
             }
             else{
               clearInterval(intr[i]);
             }
          };

          intr[i] = setInterval(timeClick, 500);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
setInterval(function(){ $('.button').click();},500);
```

Comment: It's best to not have to search the DOM every 500ms.  I suggest saving off `$('.button')` into a variable, and just using that.

Answer (score 1):

You could build a function to execute the clicks sequentially, a click every `N` specified milliseconds timeout, iterating the matched elements one by one:

Usage:

```
clickQueue($('.button'), 500);
```

The function:

```
var clickQueue = function ($els, timeout) {
  var n = $els.length, i = 0;

  function click () { // internal function
    $els.eq(i++).click(); // click the element and increment i
    if (i < n){
      setTimeout(click, timeout); // execute again if possible
    }
  }
  click(); // invoke for first time
};
```

Comment: I really like this concept, it's reusable. The only thing is that it skips the first button, i.e. it clicks all the buttons except the first one.

Comment: I think it may be with how I tested it, your example seems to work fine. I put this after your code:

$('.button').click(function(){
  $(this).css('color','green');
  });

and only the last 4 buttons out of 5 changed to green. Now, I am trying to figure out why.